# update display name of a member with GAM or admin sdk api

Tags: wiki, google-admin-sdk

I would like to set or to modify display names of members subscribed to groups I'm managing (see attached picture).
I need to do that by Groups Migration API or GAM. But members object don't include that information!

I try to execute following command:

```
gam update group test-group add member user "Pippo Paperino" pippo.paperino@email.-it
```

this don't work. :-(

Does anybody knows how to do that?

```
{
 "kind": "admin#directory#member",
 "etag": "\"enlFCt4L0xxxzRNl5h_fsrc/PLoDCCsd1WkZFMzGD8Xvw7uzSCQ\"",
 "id": "109503944206647999229",
 "email": "pippo.paperino@email.it",
 "role": "MEMBER",
 "type": "USER",
 "status": "ACTIVE",
 "delivery_settings": "ALL_MAIL"
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMazj.png)

Answer (score 0):

A member of a Group can be a user or another group.

- If the member of the group is a user, the display name corresponds to the `name` the user has in the Google Account (the `fullName`, which is formed by concatenating the `givenName` and the `familyName`): check [User resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users) . You cannot update  the display name in Groups directly. If you want that display name to change, you would have to call [Users.update](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update) in `Admin SDK > Directory API`, and provide a new user's `familyName` and `givenName`. But bear in mind that this will change the user's name everywhere, not just the display name in that group.
- If the member of the group is another group, the display name corresponds to the `name` property in the [Group resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups). If you want to update that display name, you would have to call [Groups.update](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/update) and provide your desired display name. Of course, this will change the display name not just in that group, but everywhere.

#### Reference:

- [Members](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members)
- [Groups](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups)
- [Users](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users)

I hope this is of any help.